# Laravel many-to-many relationship OrderBy

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 models in a Many to Many relationship. Let's say User and Role.
I want to sort my users based on the ASC/DESC of a field in Role.

My User & Role classes:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role','role_user');

}

class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','role_user');

}
```

I can sort the roles in each user but I cant sort the users

```
    $query = User::with(array('roles'=> function ($query)
    { 
       $query->select('role_name')->orderBy('role_name','asc'); 
    }))->get();
```

I have also tried:

```
 $query = User::with(roles)->orderBy('role_name','asc')->get();
```

But the error says `column role_name does not` exist.

Ideal result should look like this:

```
[
  {
    user_id:6
    roles: [
    "Admin",
    "Baby"
    ]
  },
  {
    user_id:2
    roles: [
    "Baby"
    ]
  },
  {
    user_id:11
    roles: [
    "Baby",
    "Cowboy"
    ]
  }
]
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: are you sure the migration is published creating a role_name column?

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi what do you mean by published? My database and tables are there with data populated in them.

Comment: okay just wanted to make sure the column exists! sharw migrations aswell

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi there is really nothing special about migrations. the pivot table holds 2 integer id's.

Comment: what if you remove the `select` and just do `$query->orderBy('role_name','asc'); `

Comment: or try `$query->orderBy('roles.role_name', 'asc')` ?

Comment: @BagusTesa It gives me  `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.role_name' in 'order clause'`

Comment: ah right, checking on the code it only recognise model's column, but not the relation column.. nevertheless, can't we inverse the approach? like fetching the data from roles first..

Comment: @BagusTesa I ended up creating a different page for my roles and querying it there since I couldn't figure out how to achieve this via eloquent

Comment: Hi @HiradRoshandel although i believe, once you have the collection `Role`s that contains `User`s, you could select the entire users inside the roles using [`map`](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_map). well, at least, you had workaround for now..

Answer (score 1):

As user can have many roles i think you can concatenate role names and then order users by concatenated string. Try this:

```
User::selectRaw('group_concat(roles.name order by roles.name asc) as role_names, users.id')->
            join('role_user','users.id','=','role_user.user_id')->
            join('roles', 'roles.id','=','role_user.role_id')->
            groupBy('user_id')->
            orderBy('role_names','desc')->
            get()
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below modification in roles() function in User Class and then fetch it with User.

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function roles()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role','role_user')
                 ->selectRaw('id,'role_name')
                 ->orderby('role_name');

   }

}

$query = User::with(roles)->get();
```

Hope this will be useful for you.

Comment: This sorts the roles not users